# Android Bluetooth device stuck in connect/disconnect loop with Linux Bluez Peripheral

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

---

For a BLE project I have been working on, I have created a smartphone application which serves as central, and a program in Linux, that serves as peripheral. After manually disconnecting via the phone, the program works as intended. But after disconnecting via the peripheral, the connection gets stuck in connect/disconnect loop.

I'm using "JustWorks" in bluetooth, which doesn't require any bonding/pairing.

The smartphone application is made in Flutter, and uses the flutter_reactive_ble library from Hue. The Linux program is written in Python, and uses the Bluezero package, but for disconnecting, I'm using:

```
subprocess.run("bluetoothctl -- disconnect", shell=True)
```

The terminal that is running the peripheral looks like this:

```
Attempting to disconnect from 58:93:C0:B5:9B:D7
Successful disconnected
[CHG] Device 58:93:C0:B5:9B:D7 Connected: no
Attempting to disconnect from 58:93:C0:B5:9B:D7
Successful disconnected
Attempting to disconnect from 58:93:C0:B5:9B:D7
Successful disconnected
```

The bluetoothctl terminal looks like this:

```
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 6E:4C:38:CB:4D:A9 Connected: yes
```

This is the btmon output: From start to end: Received data -> disconnected from peripheral -> stuck in connect/disconnect loop.

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                   #72 [hci0] 4.765604
      LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 27                 #73 [hci0] 4.855361
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x01 dlen 27                 #74 [hci0] 4.856590
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x01 dlen 81                 #75 [hci0] 4.857340
      ATT: Write Command (0x52) len 130
        Handle: 0x0026
          Data: 6c69664638704647574134704656625275514a6d727053547062486a754d4c527758674f545733496d4e566630506d385542776c7a446155482b774f506f6a6330335345796c69695438494477554e477664617431424a3373496b352f58476d507a5937676a42707462436e4574392f5858702b79426b4e77796e43694c7242
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                   #76 [hci0] 4.857646
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 24
        Max TX octets: 251
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 250
        Max RX time: 2120
@ MGMT Command: Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7             {0x0001} [hci0] 6.819215
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3              #77 [hci0] 6.819411
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #78 [hci0] 6.823217
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4              #79 [hci0] 6.881799
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10        {0x0001} [hci0] 6.882315
      Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Adve.. (0x08|0x0039) plen 6  #80 [hci0] 6.907442
        Extended advertising: Disabled (0x00)
        Number of sets: 1 (0x01)
        Entry 0
          Handle: 0x01
          Duration: 0 ms (0x00)
          Max ext adv events: 0
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #81 [hci0] 6.911608
      LE Set Extended Advertising Enable (0x08|0x0039) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Adv.. (0x08|0x0036) plen 25  #82 [hci0] 6.911986
        Handle: 0x01
        Properties: 0x0013
          Connectable
          Scannable
          Use legacy advertising PDUs: ADV_IND
        Min advertising interval: 37.500 msec (0x003c)
        Max advertising interval: 37.500 msec (0x003c)
        Channel map: 37, 38, 39 (0x07)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
        Filter policy: Allow Scan Request from Any, Allow Connect Request from Any (0x00)
        TX power: 0 dbm (0x00)
        Primary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        Secondary max skip: 0x00
        Secondary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        SID: 0x00
        Scan request notifications: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                 #83 [hci0] 6.913620
      LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (0x08|0x0036) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        TX power (selected): 0 dbm (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Adve.. (0x08|0x0039) plen 6  #84 [hci0] 6.913983
        Extended advertising: Enabled (0x01)
        Number of sets: 1 (0x01)
        Entry 0
          Handle: 0x01
          Duration: 0 ms (0x00)
          Max ext adv events: 0
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #85 [hci0] 6.918517
      LE Set Extended Advertising Enable (0x08|0x0039) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                   #86 [hci0] 7.793289
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Role: Peripheral (0x01)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x01
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13        {0x0001} [hci0] 7.793976
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used... (0x08|0x0016) plen 2  #87 [hci0] 7.794074
        Handle: 24
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 6                    #88 [hci0] 7.795376
      LE Advertising Set Terminated (0x12)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Connection handle: 24
        Number of completed extended advertising events: 20
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #89 [hci0] 7.797118
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                    #90 [hci0] 7.827428
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 24
        Algorithm: #2 (0x01)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                   #91 [hci0] 7.873271
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Features: 0xbd 0x7f 0x00 0x37 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Peripheral-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          Extended Scanner Filter Policies
          LE 2M PHY
          Stable Modulation Index - Transmitter
          Stable Modulation Index - Receiver
          LE Coded PHY
          LE Extended Advertising
          LE Periodic Advertising
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
          Periodic Advertising Sync Transfer - Sender
          Periodic Advertising Sync Transfer - Recipient
          Sleep Clock Accuracy Updates
          Connected Isochronous Stream - Central
          Connected Isochronous Stream - Peripheral
          Isochronous Channels (Host Support)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                 #92 [hci0] 8.006833
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 3 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                 #93 [hci0] 8.011070
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 3 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                 #94 [hci0] 8.011537
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 4 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                 #95 [hci0] 8.011863
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 4 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                 #96 [hci0] 8.013806
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 5 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                 #97 [hci0] 8.014120
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 5 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                 #98 [hci0] 8.015700
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 6 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                 #99 [hci0] 8.016011
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 6 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                #100 [hci0] 8.017572
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 7 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                #101 [hci0] 8.017884
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 7 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26                #102 [hci0] 8.019854
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 8 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 67
        Source CID: 80
        Source CID: 72
        Source CID: 73
        Source CID: 74
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10                #103 [hci0] 8.020183
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 8 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #104 [hci0] 8.055702
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                  #105 [hci0] 8.059275
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 24
        Max TX octets: 251
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 27
        Max RX time: 328
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #106 [hci0] 8.063411
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #107 [hci0] 8.067380
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #108 [hci0] 8.070316
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #109 [hci0] 8.072300
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5     #110 [hci0] 8.099836
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
@ MGMT Command: Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7            {0x0001} [hci0] 10.834677
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3            #111 [hci0] 10.836267
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                 #112 [hci0] 10.840869
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4            #113 [hci0] 10.889096
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10       {0x0001} [hci0] 10.889891
      Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Ad.. (0x08|0x0039) plen 6  #114 [hci0] 10.919524
        Extended advertising: Disabled (0x00)
        Number of sets: 1 (0x01)
        Entry 0
          Handle: 0x01
          Duration: 0 ms (0x00)
          Max ext adv events: 0
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4               #115 [hci0] 10.923760
      LE Set Extended Advertising Enable (0x08|0x0039) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended A.. (0x08|0x0036) plen 25  #116 [hci0] 10.924022
        Handle: 0x01
        Properties: 0x0013
          Connectable
          Scannable
          Use legacy advertising PDUs: ADV_IND
        Min advertising interval: 37.500 msec (0x003c)
        Max advertising interval: 37.500 msec (0x003c)
        Channel map: 37, 38, 39 (0x07)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
        Filter policy: Allow Scan Request from Any, Allow Connect Request from Any (0x00)
        TX power: 0 dbm (0x00)
        Primary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        Secondary max skip: 0x00
        Secondary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        SID: 0x00
        Scan request notifications: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5               #117 [hci0] 10.927608
      LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (0x08|0x0036) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        TX power (selected): 0 dbm (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Ad.. (0x08|0x0039) plen 6  #118 [hci0] 10.928040
        Extended advertising: Enabled (0x01)
        Number of sets: 1 (0x01)
        Entry 0
          Handle: 0x01
          Duration: 0 ms (0x00)
          Max ext adv events: 0
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4               #119 [hci0] 10.933897
      LE Set Extended Advertising Enable (0x08|0x0039) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                 #120 [hci0] 10.942881
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Role: Peripheral (0x01)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x01
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13       {0x0001} [hci0] 10.943295
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Use.. (0x08|0x0016) plen 2  #121 [hci0] 10.943372
        Handle: 24
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 6                  #122 [hci0] 10.944681
      LE Advertising Set Terminated (0x12)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Connection handle: 24
        Number of completed extended advertising events: 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                 #123 [hci0] 10.946984
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                  #124 [hci0] 10.979349
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 24
        Algorithm: #2 (0x01)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                 #125 [hci0] 11.024865
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Features: 0xbd 0x7f 0x00 0x37 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Peripheral-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          Extended Scanner Filter Policies
          LE 2M PHY
          Stable Modulation Index - Transmitter
          Stable Modulation Index - Receiver
          LE Coded PHY
          LE Extended Advertising
          LE Periodic Advertising
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
          Periodic Advertising Sync Transfer - Sender
          Periodic Advertising Sync Transfer - Recipient
          Sleep Clock Accuracy Updates
          Connected Isochronous Stream - Central
          Connected Isochronous Stream - Peripheral
          Isochronous Channels (Host Support)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #126 [hci0] 11.158694
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 9 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #127 [hci0] 11.159017
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 9 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #128 [hci0] 11.160874
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 10 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #129 [hci0] 11.161137
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 10 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #130 [hci0] 11.162536
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 11 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #131 [hci0] 11.162874
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 11 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #132 [hci0] 11.164513
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 12 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #133 [hci0] 11.164839
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 12 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #134 [hci0] 11.166441
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 13 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #135 [hci0] 11.166739
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 13 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 24 flags 0x02 dlen 26               #136 [hci0] 11.168433
      LE L2CAP: Enhanced Credit Connection Request (0x17) ident 14 len 18
        PSM: 39 (0x0027)
        MTU: 256
        MPS: 251
        Credits: 65535
        Source CID: 75
        Source CID: 82
        Source CID: 64
        Source CID: 65
        Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 24 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #137 [hci0] 11.168788
      LE L2CAP: Command Reject (0x01) ident 14 len 2
        Reason: Command not understood (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #138 [hci0] 11.207392
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                 #139 [hci0] 11.211700
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 24
        Max TX octets: 251
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 27
        Max RX time: 328
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #140 [hci0] 11.213812
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #141 [hci0] 11.217827
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #142 [hci0] 11.221915
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #143 [hci0] 11.225994
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #144 [hci0] 11.251600
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 24
        Count: 1
@ MGMT Command: Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7            {0x0001} [hci0] 14.821568
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3            #145 [hci0] 14.821608
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                 #146 [hci0] 14.830653
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4            #147 [hci0] 14.896228
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 24
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10       {0x0001} [hci0] 14.896709
      Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: 48:AD:99:8B:C5:3D (Resolvable)
```

---

For this project, I would like the peripheral to be able to disconnect, without getting stuck in the connect/disconnect loop.

Attempting to manually disconnect via the console in the bluetoothctl menu returns the same results.

It doesn't seem that the error is in my application. Debug statements proof that the connect method doesn't get called.

Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions for this problem?

Comment: Can you try running btmon on a separate terminal in your Linux machine then post the output here? btmon is a packet monitoring tool that will give us an understanding of why the connect/disconnect is happening.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the log.

Comment: I am Stuck on the similar issues. Can u brief me if there is any Solution for the same?